# Remove quotation mark from .txt

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I've a `txt` file with the following row type:

```
"Hello I'm in Tensorflow"
"My name is foo"
'Mr "alias" is running'
...
```

So at it can be seen, just one string per row. When I try to create a `tf.data.Dataset`, the output looks like this:

```
conver = TextLineDataset('path_to.txt')
for utter in conver:
    print(utter)
   break
# tf.Tensor(b'"Hello I'm in Tensorflow"', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

If you notice, the quotation mark `"` is still present at the beginning and end of the string (plus the defined by the tensor `'`). My desired output would be:

```
# tf.Tensor(b'Hello I'm in Tensorflow', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

That is, without the quotation marks.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Iterate over the lines and `strip(b'"')`…?!

Comment: hello @deceze i think strip is for blankspaces, I just want to drop `"` from the beginning and end of each row

Comment: It not *only* for spaces: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.strip

Comment: @deceze oh I thought you were speaking about `tf.strings.strip`. The thing is that by opening the file with `pd.read_csv()`, it reads correctly, without the quotes

Comment: Because `pd.read_csv` interprets the format as CSV, in which `"` act as delimiters and aren't part of the value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `tf.strings.regex_replace`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
conver = tf.data.TextLineDataset('/content/text.txt')

def remove_quotes(text):
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '\"', '')
  text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '\'', '')
  return text

conver = conver.map(remove_quotes)
for s in conver:
  print(s)
```

```
tf.Tensor(b'Hello Im in Tensorflow', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'My name is foo', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'Mr alias is running', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Or if you just want to remove the leading and trailing quotes then try this:

```
text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text, '^[\"\']*|[\"\']*$', '')
```

Comment: I know I can't post this type of msg, but thank you for answering most of my questions within this weeks, you've been incredible helpful to me, thx!

Answer (score 0):

The `eval()` function should do it.

```
for utter in conver:
    print(eval(utter))
   break
```

or you can simply use `replace` -

```
for utter in conver:
    print(utter.replace('"',''))
   break
```

Comment: You should be very *very* sure about all possible values before running them through `eval`!

Comment: thx for answering! but there are some strings with the value `"` in it, so i need only drop the first and last value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve quotation marks in the string that are not in the end or the start of the string -

```
for utter in conver:
    print(''.join([utter[i] if not (utter[i] == '"' and (i==0 or i==len(utter)-1)) else '' for i in range(len(utter))]))
  break
```